# Obligations when dealing with EOL IT equipment (UK)

Tags: hardware

I have been looking for a simple breakdown of the obligations of a Network Admin / IT Manager (etc) when dealing with the inevitable pile of EOL (End of life) IT equipment that comes out of a multi-site corporate setting.
(eg laptops, printers, PCs, screens, phones etc)

In the UK this is governed by the WEEE regulations, but the are so extensive and complicated that nobody seems to have a thorough understanding.

I know we have a responsibility to deal with and dispose of all dead IT kit in appropriate ways, but what are these ways?

Including but not limited to:

- Storage of EOL equipment (on-site?)
- Disposal
- Paper trail
- Anything else...

I'm not looking for signed and sealed legal advice, any pointers or just where a break-down can be obtained.

Comment: You ask for LEGAL advice? Ask a lawyer. Anything else is not reliable.

Comment: Yeah thanks, thats super useful (and the most generic possible answer)
Even the sodding government cant interpret the regs...

Comment: it is the only answer I am allowed to give you BY LAW. Giving legal advice is a very tricky thing. I say the wrong thing, you sue me. Or a lawyer does - for soliciting legal advice unlicensed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you ask for specific legal advice - which not only may change over time, but there are legal issues with giving legal advice.

Comment: You see... this is part of the problem, there is no advice available, nobody can interpret the regs. I'm not willing to pay "a lawyer" to tell me what should be made plain and simple to understand in the first place by the law-makers. I knew posting a question like this on here was unlikely to get me anywhere, but there's no need to bite my head off.

Comment: Just last week I heard from someone working in the electronics recycling industry, that EU is working on new legislation in that area, and it looks like it is likely to get passed very soon. http://law.stackexchange.com/ might be a more suitable place to ask for details. And remember that any legal advice you find online is only there to help you ask the right questions to your lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

We buy a LOT of hardware so inevitably we also have to decomm it eventually and while you can deal with this yourself often it makes sense to contact the original manufacturer and pay them to deal with it themselves. They'll do things like render disks unreadable, wipe configs from flash and deal with the waste in a 'green' way. Yes it's not free but they do a thorough job and you're legally off the hook. All the big manufacturers do this by the way, we tend not to buy from smaller ones but you will occasionally have to destroy something yourself - fire's always good and you can sell a lot of it as scrap metal.

I'm in the UK too btw and I'd agree with you on the regulations, so do yourself a favour and outsource it :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer other than "ask a lawyer" :-)
We do outsource disposal currently, so that side of things is basically dealt with in accordance to (the disposal company's understanding on) the WEEE regs.
Where it starts to get a bit more complicated is internal procedures, IE storage - the reason the question came about was actually that someone said that the way we are storing some old kit before disposal (corner of the server room in the "dead pile") was potentially legally iffy...

Comment: I see, well in that case so long as the 'spinney' disks use perpendicular technology (i.e. bought after about 2009) then a single 'zero-out' of the entire array will be good enough to satisfy anyone. If they're older you may need to do it 7 times or whatever. Either way I'd wipe if before powering it off - actually we had to do this just the other on some old HP P6550's we decommed.